# Ionic default back navigation is not working in all the pages - ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation, ionic3

I am working on an ionic project that has several pages out of which some pages have the back arrow that takes to the previous page however this does not seems to work fine on the rest of pages. I believe that the back arrow is default as i have implemented same header code for both the pages but one of them has the back arrow displayed but another does not has.

**Page 1 header code // This has the back arrow**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary" primary>
    <ion-title>Product Detail</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="cart()">
          <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

**Page 2 // No back arrow displayed**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary" primary>
    <ion-title>Shop Single</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="cart()">
          <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Also the .ts files for the same too do not seem to have much difference.

Comment: Maybe for Page2, while pushing into nav stack, you may popping the parent nav(making page2 as root). I dont know the case, just trying to hint! If thats not the case, can you please show the code for pushing Page2?

Comment: the navigation is from home to page 1  and home to page 2.

Comment: Is the page2 navigation done by modal controller?

Comment: i have just added them to the side menu and created references for the same in the corresponding files.

Comment: Im sorry, i cant help unless there is some code here

Comment: constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'option1', component: page1 },
      { title: 'option2', component: page2}
    ];

  }

Comment: This is how i have added them to the side menu and page loaded on clicking the option.